# Checkboxes in single form for multiple objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In trying to create a single form to add multiple objects, I followed this tutorial and got it working.  Problem is, I can only enter values for string attributes and not for boolean attributes as it messes the params up.  Where is my form going wrong?
http://vicfriedman.github.io/blog/2015/07/18/create-multiple-objects-from-single-form-in-rails/

```
<%= form_tag boa_constrictors_litter_hash_path do %>
  <% @litter.each do |snake| %>
    <%= fields_for 'offspring[]', snake do |f| %> 
        <%= f.hidden_field :type, :value => "BoaConstrictor" %>
        <%= f.text_field :name, placeholder: "Name"%>
        <%= f.label :gender %>
        <%=f.select :gender, options_for_select([['Male', 'Male'], 
            ['Female', 'Female']]) %>
        <%= f.hidden_field :year, :value => "2017" %>
        <%= f.label :available %>
        <%= f.check_box :available %>
        <%= f.label :private %>
        <%= f.check_box :private %>
        <%= f.label "Notes" %>
        <%= f.text_field :notes %>
        <% if @dame.hypo? or @sire.hypo? %>
            <%= f.label "Hypo" %>
            <%= f.check_box :hypo %>
        <% end %>
        <% if @dame.img? or @sire.img? %>
            <%= f.label "IMG" %>
            <%= f.check_box :img %>
        <% end %>   
    <% end %><br>
<% end %>    
<%= submit_tag %>
```

Ex; Creating two snakes, one named "first" w/ available: true and the other named "second" sends the following params which creates three snakes with incorrect attributes:

```
"offspring"=>[{"type"=>"BoaConstrictor", "name"=>"first", "gender"=>"Male", 
"year"=>"2017", "available"=>"0"}, {"available"=>"1", "private"=>"0", 
"notes"=>"", "hypo"=>"0", "img"=>"0", "type"=>"BoaConstrictor", 
"name"=>"second", "gender"=>"Male", "year"=>"2017"}, {"available"=>"0", 
"private"=>"0", "notes"=>"", "hypo"=>"0", "img"=>"0"}], "commit"=>"Save 
changes"}
```

If I entered two animals, one named "first" with notes "works" and the other named "second " with notes "now", it gives the correct params and creates two animals correctly.

```
"offspring"=>[{"type"=>"BoaConstrictor", "name"=>"first", "gender"=>"Male", 
"year"=>"2017", "available"=>"0", "private"=>"0", "notes"=>"works", 
"hypo"=>"0"}, {"type"=>"BoaConstrictor", "name"=>"second", "gender"=>"Male", 
"year"=>"2017", "available"=>"0", "private"=>"0", "notes"=>"now", 
"hypo"=>"0"}], "commit"=>"Save changes"}
```

If I check any of the booleans in the form, the params chop at that attribute and repeat leading to extraneous objects and messing up the attributes of any of the objects that follow.

**Solved**
Check_box does not work correctly for attributes within an array as documented here: https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/check_box

Solution was to use check_box_tag
Instead of <%= f.check_box :private %>, using <%= check_box_tag 'offspring[][private]' %> works fine.

Comment: What do you mean by 'not for boolean attributes as it messes the params up' ? what mess exactly ?

Comment: Updated my Q, thanks

Comment: can you check the rendered HTML for the checkboxes, what are the values of names?

Comment: <input name="offspring[][attribute]" type="hidden" value="0">
<input type="checkbox" value="1" name="offspring[][attribute]" id="offspring__attribute">

Comment: It should show the name attribute with auto increment number, that's why.

Comment: I have another question, why you have the checkbox as hidden for the first control?

Comment: I have no idea why it is showing as hidden.  That is what my form code above is generating.  Is f.check_box not appropriate for setting an object's boolean attributes here?  Totally lost on why this isn't working.

Comment: for other controls do you see autonumber  at the end of control name ?

Comment: No, autonumber is not present anywhere in the rendered HTML

Comment: check the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`check_box` does not work correctly for attributes within an array as documented [here](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/check_box).

Solution was to use `check_box_tag`:
Instead of `<%= f.check_box :private %>`,
using `<%= check_box_tag 'offspring[][private]' %>` works fine.